# Kotlin outer scope

Tags: kotlin

I would like to access the scope of the calling class when creating an "anonymous inner class"
in Kotlin. What would be the equivalent of Java's `OuterScope.this` syntax? example :

```
open class SomeClass {
    open fun doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}

class MyClass {
    fun someFunc() {
        object : SomeClass() {
            override fun doSomething() {
                super<SomeClass>.doSomething()
                // Access the outer class context, in Java
                // this would be MyClass.this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
this@MyClass
```

JFYI:
the same syntax for access to receiver of extension function:

```
fun MyClass.foo() {
    // in some nested thing:
    this@foo
    //...
}
```

Kotlin Reference: [This expressions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html)

Answer (score 14):

in my case i accessed it like : `this@MainActivity`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   inner class Anon : Observer<PagedList<ApplicationUsers>> {
        override fun onChanged(pagedList: PagedList<ApplicationUsers>?) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, in case inside `onChanged()` I want to access class Anon, so is it possible?